# Method that accepts either one of two interfaces

Tags: c#, .net

### The problem

I have two interfaces `IImporter` and `IExporter` and a class that handles instances of those interfaces:

```
class IoManager
{
    public ReadOnlyCollection<IImporter> Importers { get; } 
    public ReadOnlyCollection<IExporter> Exporters { get; }

    // ...
}
```

In this class I want to implement a method `Add(...)` that can add either an importer or an exporter.

I know I could create an overload for both interfaces like

```
public void Add(IExporter exporter);
public void Add(IImporter importer);
```

The problem is if I want to add an object that implements both interfaces like `CsvIo : IImporter, IExporter` via the `Add(...)` function, I get an ambigious call compiler error because `CsvIo` is accepted by both overloads.

### What I don't want to do

- I don't want to rename the overloads to different names, because most types implement both interfaces and I want a coherent behavior for types that implement `IExporter`, `IImporter` or both.
- I don't want to create a "parent" interface that is implemented by both interfaces, because this seems like a *hacky* solution
- I don't want to cast types in the `Add(...)` call, like `Add((IImporter) CsvIoInstance)`, because that suggests that only the importer of this type is used. But both overloads check if the object implements both interfaces and adds it to both lists accordingly.

### The question

Is there a way of accepting the different types in a coherent manner (so that the call looks the same for each type)?

### Edit

To clarify my implementation: this is part of a plugin system. I want to add multiple ways of storing my data (so that it can be used by other applications). The `IExporter` interface is used for storing the data while the `IImporter` interface loads the data. The `IoManager` manages all registered plugins. And of course it is possible (and probably common) that a class implements both, exporting and importing of a certain file format. This is why I wanted the `Add(...)` function to be similar for all cases.

However, thinking about it again (as already stated in the comments) the plugins are only known at runtime which makes ambiguity an obsolete problem I think. So this is only relevant for built in types.

Comment: Should the `Add` method add the argument to both collections if it implements both interfaces?

Comment: `Is there a way of accepting the different types in a coherent manner (so that the call looks the same for each type)?` Given your constraints (not using a base type, and not casting the object), nope.

Comment: *I don't want to create a "parent" interface that is implemented by both interfaces, because this seems like a hacky solution* Why is this *hacky*? It is the way to go, IMHO.

Comment: I would create a single `Add` method which will check what interfaces are implemented on the passed object. Then execute the appropriate code for all implementated interfaces.

Comment: "..., because this seems like a hacky solution" ... well that means that your design _already is_ hacky, because that is actually exactly what you're trying to do, but without admitting it by giving it a name.

Comment: What would you expect to happen if an object *does* implement both interfaces? It's very unclear to me what you expect the functionality to be, to be honest.

Comment: And do you expect the behaviour to vary by whether the fact that a type implements both interfaces is known at compile time or whether it's only known at execution time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd like to focus on one sentence in particular:

> I don't want to cast types in the `Add(...)` call, like `Add((IImporter) CsvIoInstance)`, because that suggests that only the importer of this type is used. But both overloads **check if the object implements both interfaces and adds it to both lists accordingly**.

Your current design already gives up one of the goals of type safety: to avoid runtime type checking.  Ideally, a method that takes an `IImporter` parameter should *only* use that parameter as an `IImporter`.  This forms a sort of "contract" between the caller of the method and the implementer: the implementer trusts that the caller will provide what it needs, and the caller trusts that the implementer will only use it in that way.  (See also: [Principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).)

Imagine that you're a consumer of this class.  There is a collection of `IImporters` and a method with the signature `Add(IImporter foo)`.  What would you expect that method to do?  *I* would expect it to add `foo` to the list of `IImporters` - I would *not* expect it to also do something else because my object happened to implement another interface (such as `IExporter`).  Using the type system in this way "betrays" the contract you've established with the caller.

Change your method names to `AddImporter` and `AddExporter`, and then have each method *only* add the parameter to the corresponding list.  That solves the problem with overload resolution, and means that the caller is getting exactly what they asked for.

Comment: Although I didn't want to go this way, the community convinced me to change my mind. I accept this answer because the explanation why to go this way is the best among all given answers. IMO at least.

Comment: Are you opposed to interface inheritance in general?

Comment: @BJMyers nevermind I finally read the sentence you bolded and it makes sense now

Answer (score 2):

There's an obvious solution to this problem, but you rule it out with this statement:

> I don't want to rename the overloads to different names, because most types implement both interfaces and I want a coherent behavior for types that implement IExporter, IImporter or both.

The problem is that you want to do this:

```
public void Add(IExporter exporter);
public void Add(IImporter importer);
```

But you don't want to do this:

```
public void AddExporter(IExporter exporter);
public void AddImporter(IImporter importer);
```

Why? You can call the first one an "overloaded method", which it technically is, but it's really just two methods with the same name.

Overloading is when you have have a method that does one thing, but you can do it with different sets of parameters. These two methods actually do two different things. One adds an `IExporter` and one adds an `IImporter`. So there's nothing 'incoherent' about giving different names to different methods that do different things. It would be much, much worse to add extra interfaces and complication to your classes just to manipulate the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

It's similar to your request for no parent interface, but what you should have is a child interface that combines the two.

```
public interface IImporterExporter : IImporter, IExporter {
}
```

Implement it on your class instead of the two separate interfaces:

```
class ImporterExporter : IImporterExporter {
}
```

And then write a third overload:

```
public void Add(IImporterExporter importerExporter) {
   // decide what to do if both interfaces are implemented
}
```

There is a reason why you end up with the ambiguity problem, and that is because either of the overloads could be correct, or maybe even both of them are correct at the same time. You need to resolve the ambiguity by deciding what to do in that case. Since C# does not have type unions, you must declare a separate interface which unifies them.

Note that this is **not** "hacky", but is actually good design to combine simpler interfaces into more complex ones. This allows for cleaner and more precise code, which is a good thing. But regardless of that, even if you don't like the idea of combining interfaces for some reason, it is still necessary in C# in order to avoid this exact problem.

Without the third interface, all you're left with is looking for something else that both types have in common, and without a parent interface, you're basically just left with `object`. This would allow for a single method, but you would lose the benefits of the type system.

```
public void Add(object obj) {
   var maybeImporter = obj as IImporter;
   var maybeExporter = obj as IExporter;

   if (maybeImporter != null && maybeExporter != null) {
      // do something if both are implemented
   } else if (maybeImporter != null) { 
      // importer only
   } else
      // exporter only
   }
}
```

Comment: @RenéVogt Well, he said he could write an overload, *except for the ambiguity*. This resolves the ambiguity.

Comment: This only "solves" the problem if *every* class that implements both interfaces *also* implements the child interface.  If any of these interfaces are public, he still opens himself up to overload ambiguities that would be far more confusing (IMO) than the original.

Comment: @BJMyers *This only "solves" the problem if every class that implements both interfaces also implements the child interface.* That's not a problem. Any class that implements both interfaces should be rewritten to use the combined interface instead. This is a commonly occurring problem in C# and this is the way to solve it.

Comment: `Any class that implements both interfaces should be rewritten to use the combined interface instead.`  IMO that's a poor way to design an inheritance hierarchy.  It introduces a hidden requirement that requires an implementer of an interface to *know* that there is another, better interface that must be implemented instead for things to work correctly.

Comment: @BJMyers I don't see why needing to know about the existence of types in your own code base is a problem. My personal examples that I'm constantly using are `IIntegralKeyObject`, and `INamedObject`. I combine those into `INamedIntegralKeyObject`, not even to resolve an ambiguity, but because it's just cleaner to say. Notice also that as soon as you have this third interface, very often you will discover code that logically belongs there, where before you weren't really sure where to put it.

Comment: I see a difference there - does your code stop working if something implements `IIntegralKeyObject` and `INamedObject` instead of `INamedIntegralKeyObject`?

Comment: @BJMyers There is no ambiguity between those, so no. But nothing implements them separately anyway. `INamedIntegralKeyObject` is more precise and I know immediately to replace occurrences of the less precise interfaces with the more precise one.